How to prepare a spring cloud function for multiple multipart file uploads POST endpoint?
Description
I need to create a spring cloud function for an endpoint similar to this:
POST /api/config/user
and i need to post multiple multipart files as form-data which are:
userId: string
whitelistFile: multipart file
blacklistFile: multipart file

I am not able to create the function for the above endpoint because i get an error related to cannot cast... no matter how i try to prepare the function.
Additional question

How do i specific the POST and GET method for the specific functions?
How do i specific the endpoint like /api/config/user for spring cloud functions?

Please do let me know if my basics is not strong enough. I am just starting out with spring cloud functions and could not properly understand the spring cloud functions offical documentation.
public Consumer<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> userConfig() {return (requestBody) -> {}} 

I tried out with multivalue map and map as well but it throws the cannot cast to multivalue map error.
I also tried using flux of MultivalueMap seeing few of the suggestions. It does not throw any error and neither does it hit the endpoint.
